# How to force a browser to prompt for client certificate, even when one was already previously added

Tags: ssl-certificate

Any way to force the browser to prompt for a client certificate, even if another one was already installed?

At that apache level? 
At the browser level?

I'm totally cool with a solution that is browser-dependent because i'm only dealing with the major browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Revoke the old cert, in the server Cert Store.  That'll make it invalid from the server, and ALL clients/browsers will re-request a valid cert - at that point your new one is the only one available.

For a Windows server, invoke the cert store on the server thus:

Run "MMC"

- File menu | Add/Remove Snap-ins
- Select Certificates
- Select Computer Certificates
- Select Local Computer
- Finish

  Now, close the add wizard. At this point the Certificates module will be loaded in MMC.

The "Personal" section of the cert store will show certificates on the server.  Locate the old cert, and revoke it. At this point, only the current cert should be listed.

For Unix/Linux installations, the process is a bit different. Refer to this HowTo to see details.

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SSL-Certificates-HOWTO/x195.html

Now that you have the server set up, HURL inbound port 80 traffic to port 443 (HTTPS) which should cause all browsers to download and accept the new cert.

(If revocation isn't an option, then you might have to redirect traffic to another server with just the new cert installed.)

Comment: Revoke the old cert - you mean through the browser right? because that's the step that's annoying. having to keep going in and manually changing it each time. easy to forget. would rather have a prompt pop up.

Comment: No I mean revoke the cert in the cert store.  

That'll make it invalid from the server, and ALL clients/browsers will re-request a valid cert - at that point your new one is the only one available.

invoke the cert store on the server thus:

`Run "MMC" 
file | Add/Remove Snap-ins
Select Certificates
Select Computer Certificates
Select Local Computer
Finish
close the add wizard`

The "Personal" section of the cert store will show certificates on the server.

Comment: The above is for a Windows Server, but on a *nix machine, you should be able to browse the cert store directly, and either revoke or delete the old cert.

Comment: wow that's pretty solid advise. I'm giving it a go.